# Vagrant gem install not working

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I am new to vagrant and I'm trying to follow a tutorial I found online for setting up an open-source web application. I have installed vagrant successfully. My problem is that when I try to run the command

> vagrant gem install "anything"

I get the error

```
Usage: vagrant [-v] [-h] command [<args>]

    -v, --version                    Print the version and exit.
    -h, --help                       Print this help.

Available subcommands:
     box
     destroy
     halt
     init
     package
     plugin
     provision
     reload
     resume
     ssh
     ssh-config
     status
     suspend
     up

For help on any individual command run `vagrant COMMAND -h`
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: You got it all wrong, gem install is a ruby command. Vagrant is a VM management utility.

Comment: @Radoo - actually, if you go out and look, you'll find that much of the documentation, and many of the tutorials out there indicate that "vagrant gem install" should be valid. If I'm reading correctly, whether this is valid or not may vary depending on how Vagrant itself was installed, oddly enough.

Comment: `vagrant gem install` is for Vagrant version <= 1.0.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with that as well. Just use:

```
vagrant plugin install any-plugin
```